# How can I prevent players from overwriting one another in tic tac toe?

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

I have tried to program a tic tac toe game in C# (with the help of tutorials). Overall it seems to be working fine (although the amount of code seems very excessive so sorry for that) but there appears to be one problem: Say, player 1 decides on row 1, column 1 and player 2 does the same afterwards, then player 2 overwrites player 1.
So far, this is the code:

```
namespace TicTacToe
{
    class Program
    {
    static int turns = 1;
    static char[] board =
    {
        ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '
    };
    static char playerSignature = 'X'; 
    private static void Introduction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a simple TicTacToe game. Enter y if you have played before and n if you are new to this.");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if (input1 == "n")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TicTacToeRules:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. The game is played on a grid that's 3 squares by 3 squares.");
            Console.WriteLine("2. You are X, your friend is O. Players take turns putting their marks in empty squares.");
            Console.WriteLine("3. The first player to get 3 of her marks in a row (up, down, across, or diagonally) is the winner.");
            Console.WriteLine("4. When all 9 squares are full, the game is over.");
            Console.WriteLine("If you have read the rules, press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            DrawBoard(board);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Alright, let's get started, you are X, your friend is O.");
            DrawBoard(board);
        }
    }
    private static void PlayAgain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Play again? y/n");
        string playagain = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (playagain)
        {
            case "n":
                Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!");
                Console.Clear();
                break;
            case "y":
                Console.Clear();
                ResetBoard();
                break;
        }
    }
    private static void DrawBoard(char[] board)
    {

        string row = "| {0} | {1} | {2} |";
        string sep = "|___|___|___|";
        Console.WriteLine(" ___ ___ ___ ");
        Console.WriteLine(row, board[0], board[1], board[2]);
        Console.WriteLine(sep);
        Console.WriteLine(row, board[3], board[4], board[5]);
        Console.WriteLine(sep);
        Console.WriteLine(row, board[6], board[7], board[8]);
        Console.WriteLine(sep);
    }
    private static void ResetBoard()
    {
        char[] newBoard =
        {
        ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '
        };
        board = newBoard;
        DrawBoard(board);
        turns = 0;
    }
    private static void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's a draw!\n" +
                            "Press any key to play again.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        ResetBoard();
        //DrawBoard(board);
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Introduction();
        while(true)
        {
            bool isrow = false;
            bool iscol = false;
            int row = 0;
            int col = 0;
                while (!isrow)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose a row (1-3): ");
                    try
                    {
                        row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 3.");
                    }
                    if (row == 1 || row == 2 || row == 3)
                    {
                        isrow = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid row!");
                    }
                }
                while (!iscol)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose a column (1-3): ");
                    try
                    {
                        col = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 3.");
                    }
                    if (col == 1 || col == 2 || col == 3)
                    {
                        iscol = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid column!");
                    }
                }
            int[] input = { row, col };
            int player = 2;
            if (player == 2)
            {
                player = 1;
                XorO(player, input);
            }
            else
            {
                player = 2;
                XorO(player, input);
            }
            DrawBoard(board);
            turns++;
            CheckForDiagonal();
            CheckForVertical();
            CheckForHorizontal();
            if (turns == 10 && (board[0] == playerSignature && board[1] == playerSignature && board[2] == playerSignature && board[3] == playerSignature &&
                board[4] == playerSignature && board[5] == playerSignature && board[6] == playerSignature && board[7] == playerSignature && board[8] == playerSignature))
            {
                Draw();
            }
        }
    }
    private static void CheckForVertical()
    {
        char[] PlayerSignature = { 'O', 'X' };
        foreach (char Signature in PlayerSignature)
        {
            if (board[0] == playerSignature && board[3] == playerSignature && board[6] == playerSignature ||
            board[1] == playerSignature && board[4] == playerSignature && board[7] == playerSignature ||
            board[2] == playerSignature && board[5] == playerSignature && board[8] == playerSignature)
            {
                if (playerSignature == 'X')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations Player 1, that's a vertical win!\n" +
                        "Play again (y/n)?");
                    string playagain = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (playagain == "y")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        ResetBoard();
                        turns = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations Player 2, that's a vertical win!\n" +
                        "Play again (y/n)?");
                    string playagain = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (playagain == "y")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        ResetBoard();
                        turns = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static void CheckForHorizontal()
    {
        char[] PlayerSignature = { 'O', 'X' };
        foreach (char Signature in PlayerSignature)
        {
            if (board[0] == playerSignature && board[1] == playerSignature && board[2] == playerSignature ||
                board[3] == playerSignature && board[4] == playerSignature && board[5] == playerSignature ||
                board[6] == playerSignature && board[7] == playerSignature && board[8] == playerSignature)
            {
                if (playerSignature == 'X')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations Player 1, that's a horizontal win!\n" +
                        "Play again (y/n)?");
                    string playagain = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (playagain == "y")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        ResetBoard();
                        turns = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations Player 2, that's a horizontal win!\n" +
                        "Play again (y/n)?");
                    string playagain = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (playagain == "y")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        ResetBoard();
                        turns = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static void CheckForDiagonal()
    {
        char[] PlayerSignature = { 'O', 'X' };
        foreach (char Signature in PlayerSignature)
        {
            if (board[6] == playerSignature && board[4] == playerSignature && board[2] == playerSignature ||
            board[0] == playerSignature && board[4] == playerSignature && board[8] == playerSignature)
            {
                if (playerSignature == 'X')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations Player 1, that's a diagonal win!\n" +
                        "Play again (y/n)?");
                    string playagain = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (playagain == "y")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        ResetBoard();
                        turns = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations Player 2, that's a diagonal win!\n" +
                        "Play again (y/n)?");
                    string playagain = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (playagain == "y")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        ResetBoard();
                        turns = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    private static void XorO(int player, int[] input)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            playerSignature = 'X';
        }
        else if (player == 2)
        {
            playerSignature = 'O';
        }

        if (input[0] == 1 && input[1] == 1)
        {
            board[0] = playerSignature;
        }
        else if (input[0] == 1 && input[1] == 2)
        {
            board[1] = playerSignature;
        }
        else if (input[0] == 1 && input[1] == 3)
        {
            board[2] = playerSignature;
        }
        else if (input[0] == 2 && input[1] == 1)
        {
            board[3] = playerSignature;
        }
        else if (input[0] == 2 && input[1] == 2)
        {
            board[4] = playerSignature;
        }
        else if (input[0] == 2 && input[1] == 3)
        {
            board[5] = playerSignature;
        }
        else if (input[0] == 3 && input[1] == 1)
        {
            board[6] = playerSignature;
        }
        else if (input[0] == 3 && input[1] == 2)
        {
            board[7] = playerSignature;
        }
        else if (input[0] == 3 && input[1] == 3)
        {
            board[8] = playerSignature;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have tried adding something like this: if(input[0] == 1 && input[1] == 1 && (board[0] != 'X' && board[0] != 'O') in the XorO method. But that didn't solve my issue.

Does somebody maybe have some suggestions as to how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing way too much work in some of those methods...

For instance, here's a shorter `XorO()` method that also makes sure the spot is BLANK before assigning it to a player:

```
private static void XorO(int player, int[] input)
{
    playerSignature = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';
    int index = ((input[0] - 1) * 3) + (input[1] - 1);
    if (board[index] == ' ') {
        board[index] = playerSignature;
    }
    else {
        // ... output an error message? ...
        Console.WriteLine("That spot is already taken!");
    }
}
```

> Could you maybe explain why you set index the way you did?

Sure! Here is the layout of the board, 3 rows with 3 cols, and the corresponding Index value of each position:

```
  1 2 3
1 0 1 2
2 3 4 5
3 6 7 8
```

Note that because there are 3 columns, the value of the Index as we move down from one row to the next in the same column goes up by 3. Also note that the starting values in column 1 for each row are 0, 3, and 6, which are all multiples of 3. So to convert your row value from 1, 2, and 3 into 0, 3, and 6, we first subtract 1 from the row value and then multiply it by 3.

Next, each column simply increments by one as you move to the right. Thus we subtract one from the column value and add that to the computed beginning row value. This maps the (row, col) to the indices 0 through 8, seen here as a single dimension array:

```
1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3 | 2,1 | 2,2 | 2,3 | 3,1 | 3,2 | 3,3
 0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8
```

> But how was am I supposed to think of something like that? I would
> never have thought of that.

It's a fairly common setup to represent a 2D structure in a single dimensional array, known as a [compact layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Compact_layouts). The math involved to convert a row/column to the equivalent index value or vice-versa is just something that all programmers learn at some point.

Comment: Oh, that's way more effective. Wouldn't have thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: Could you maybe explain why you set index the way you did? I don't really get it sorry. I think my problem is that when I see a problem I don't really know how to solve it past a certain level of complexity unless I look at different solutions... Any tips for that?

Comment: Like, I get that index exists to calculate the position that the players input (row, column) dictates. But how was am I supposed to think of something like that? I would never have thought of that.

Comment: See new comments and explanation at the bottom of the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you, what else could and should I shorten in the program?

Answer (score 0):

Lot of refactoring here, look closely:

```
class Program
{
    
    static int turns;
    static char[] board;
    static bool playerOne;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Introduction();

        bool playAgain = true;
        while (playAgain)
        {
            ResetBoard();                
            bool gameOver = false;
            while (!gameOver)
            {
                DrawBoard(board);
                int row = getNumber(true);
                int col = getNumber(false);
                if (XorO(row, col)) {
                    turns++; // valid move was made
                    String msg = "";
                    String playerNumber = playerOne ? "1" : "2";
                    if (CheckForDiagonal())
                    {
                        gameOver = true;
                        msg = "Congratulations Player " + playerNumber + ", that's a diagonal win!";
                    }
                    else if (CheckForVertical())
                    {
                        gameOver = true;
                        msg = "Congratulations Player " + playerNumber + ", that's a vertical win!";
                    }
                    else if (CheckForHorizontal())
                    {
                        gameOver = true;
                        msg = "Congratulations Player " + playerNumber + ", that's a horizontal win!";
                    }
                    else if (turns == 9)
                    {
                        gameOver = true;
                        msg = "It's a draw!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerOne = !playerOne;
                    }

                    if (gameOver)
                    {
                        DrawBoard(board); // show last move
                        Console.WriteLine(msg);
                    }
                }                    
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Play again (y/n)?");
            string response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            playAgain = (response == "y");
        }
    }

    private static void ResetBoard()
    {
        turns = 0;
        playerOne = true;
        board = new char[] {
            ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '
        };
    }

    private static void Introduction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a simple TicTacToe game.\nEnter y if you have played before and n if you are new to this.");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        Console.Clear();
        if (input1 == "n")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TicTacToeRules:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. The game is played on a grid that's 3 squares by 3 squares.");
            Console.WriteLine("2. You are X, your friend is O. Players take turns putting their marks in empty squares.");
            Console.WriteLine("3. The first player to get 3 of her marks in a row (up, down, across, or diagonally) is the winner.");
            Console.WriteLine("4. When all 9 squares are full, the game is over.");
            Console.WriteLine("If you have read the rules, press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();               
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Alright, let's get started, you are X, your friend is O.");
        }
    }

    private static void DrawBoard(char[] board)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" ___ ___ ___ ");
        for(int r=1; r<=3;r++)
        {
            Console.Write("|");
            for(int c=1; c<=3; c++)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0} |", board[(r - 1) * 3 + (c - 1)]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("|___|___|___|");
        }            
    }

    private static int getNumber(bool row)
    {
        int value = -1;
        string description = row ? "row" : "column";
        bool isValid = false;
        while (!isValid)
        {
            Console.Write("Player '" + (playerOne ? "X" : "O")  + "', choose a " + description + " (1-3): ");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
            {
                if (value >= 1 && value <= 3)
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 3.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid " + description + "!");
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    private static bool XorO(int row, int col)
    {
        int index = ((row - 1) * 3) + (col - 1);
        if (board[index] == ' ')
        {
            board[index] = playerOne ? 'X' : 'O';
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That spot is already taken!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static bool CheckForDiagonal()
    {
        return ((board[6] != ' ' && board[4] == board[6] && board[2] == board[6]) ||
            (board[0] != ' ' && board[4] == board[0] && board[8] == board[0]));
    }

    private static bool CheckForVertical()
    {
        for(int c=0; c<=2; c++)
        {
            if (board[c] != ' ' && board[c+3] == board[c] && board[c+6] == board[c])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static bool CheckForHorizontal()
    {
        for (int r=0; r<=6; r=r+3)
        {
            if (board[r] != ' ' && board[r + 1] == board[r] && board[r + 2] == board[r])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```